# CSV export not sorting the data in tabs mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a script that exports SQL query to CSV, when I export it, the data is in the correct columns and the tabs are correct on my excel. But on different excel versions the data is not sorted, the columns are correct in the first row but the data below is not correct. This is result I receive in the incorrect version on the second where the data displays.

```
3283;"Jame Bond";"Clint Josh";"a@A.d";"3";"3";"3";"3 3";"";"";"";
```

CSV export script

```
$sql_new = urldecode($_GET['r']);
$sql_new = str_replace('\\','',$sql_new);


$hostname = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "mydb";


mysql_connect($hostname, $user, $password)
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database)
or die ('Could not select database ' . mysql_error());

// create empty variable to be filled with export data
$csv_export = '';

// query to get data from database
$query = mysql_query($sql_new);
$field = mysql_num_fields($query);

// create line with field names
for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
$csv_export.= mysql_field_name($query,$i).';';
}
// newline (seems to work both on Linux & Windows servers)
$csv_export.= '
';

// loop through database query and fill export variable
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
// create line with field values
for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
$csv_export.= '"'.$row[mysql_field_name($query,$i)].'";';
}   
$csv_export.= '
';  
}

// Export the data and prompt a csv file for download
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
echo($csv_export);
```

Comment: It depends on the SQL. Does it contain an ORDER BY? However providing the sql query in the request parameters (the query string in your case) is dangerous. It allows for SQL injections.

Comment: On it does not have ORDER BY